# how the "disableRightClick" function is called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How is the `disableRightClick` function called in below script, and what does the the declaration `document.oncontextmenu=disableRightClick` do? Please explain.

```js
document.oncontextmenu = disableRightClick;
// how this function is called 
function disableRightClick(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    event.returnValue = false
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>On this page right click is disabled</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `document.oncontextmenu` is the event when the right mouse button is clicked.
`document.oncontextmenu = disableRightClick;` This line is watching the document for the right click event and when that happens it calls the function `disableRightClick`. In my example I moved the event to the `<h1>` tag so it can demonstrate this.

> An event handler property for right-click events on the window. Unless
>   the default behavior is prevented (see examples below on how to do
>   this), the browser context menu will activate (though IE8 has a bug
>   with this and will not activate the context menu if a contextmenu
>   event handler is defined). Note that this event will occur with any
>   non-disabled right-click event and does not depend on an element
>   possessing the "contextmenu" attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncontextmenu

This example I put the event only on the header tag so it only disables the default right click event if you are right clicking on the header tag.

```js
//document.oncontextmenu = disableRightClick;
// how this function is called 
function disableRightClick(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    event.returnValue = false
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 oncontextmenu="disableRightClick(); return false;">On this header right click is disabled</h1>
```